# React form refreshes the entire page onSubmit and setState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, setstate, onsubmit

[image: Error on console]
I am making a get request to https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/ to get one word
I display that word on my page, and ask the user to type that word in the input box below. 
Once the user types it, and presses submit or enter, I check and see if the word is correct, and if it is, i do another get request to get a new word. but this refreshes my entire page, and the score counter does not increase
Not sure what i am doing wrong.
Also event.preventDefault() does not work as it is intended

```
import React from 'react';
import getWord from './API/Word';
import key from './API/Key';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: '',
        word: null,
        score: 0
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventdefault();
        if (this.state.word === this.state.value) {
            this.setState({score: this.state.score + 1});
            this.getWord();
        }
    }

    getWord() {
        getWord.get(`/word?key=${key}&number=1`)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({word: response.data[0]})
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWord();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className = 'ui container'>
                <p>The Word: {this.state.word}</p>
                <br></br>
                <form className = "ui form" onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className = "ui field">
                        <label>Type the word: </label>
                        <input 
                            type = "text" 
                            value = {this.state.value} 
                            onChange = {(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
                <br></br>
                Score: {this.state.score}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

I get this error message very quickly in my console and then it disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with the `handleSubmit`function.

You have a typo in `preventDefault`. It needs a capital D.

And because you have written the function with a normal declaration, `this` is not bound. So you either have to bind it on your own

```
onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
```

or better convert it to an arrow function:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
...
}
```

With this the function will be automatically bound by React.

Comment: typo.. *arrow function and not named function.